# Data type that's promotable to the kind level with only one value

Tags: haskell, type-families, data-kinds

I understand I can promote `Bool` to the kind level like so, where `Bool` can potentially be `True` or `False`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

type family TF t :: Bool
type instance TF Int = True
type instance TF Bool = False
```

I wanted instead to promote `()`, which of course only has one value `()`. But this doesn't seem to work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

type family TF t :: ()
type instance TF Int = ()
type instance TF Bool = ()
```

I guess I could just use `Bool` and `True`, but is there a one valued type that can be promoted to the kind level?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try use `'()` instead of `()` at type level:

```
type family ToNull t :: ()
type instance ToNull Int = '()
type instance ToNull Bool = '()
```

Also `True` and `False` are actually shorthands for `'True` and `'False` at type level.

The problem is there are four `()` in the scope:

1. the ordinary type `()` of kind `*`
2. the only constructor of 1 which is also `()`
3. the kind `()` promoted from 1
4. the type `'()` of kind `()` promoted from 2, which has a type synonym `()` by default

without the sometimes optional single quote, 1 and 4 are ambiguous.

You may check the user guide of GHC for details:[7.9. Datatype promotion](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/promotion.html)

Comment: Thanks. Just curious, is `'True` and `'False` magic or can I define `()` likewise?

Comment: @Clinton `True` and `False` are type synonyms of `'True` and `'False`, defined by `DataKinds` language extension for convenience. It's OK for Bool but when the type and the constructor have the same name there is ambiguity, so the usually optional single-quote is necessary.

Comment: There's even a fifth `()` for extra confusion: the empty constraint.

Comment: @Clinton, note that it's considered good style to use the single quote even when it's optional.